# Conversion of Elastic list data output to R data frame slow

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I have an output from Elastic that takes very long to convert to an R data frame. I have tried multiple options; and feel there may be some trick there to quicken the process.

The structure of the list is as follows.  The list has aggregated data over 29 days (say). If lets say the Elastic query output is in list 'v_day' then l[[5]]$articles_over_time$buckets[1:29] represents each of the 29 days

```
length(v_day[[5]]$articles_over_time$buckets)
[1] 29
page(v_day[[5]]$articles_over_time$buckets[[1]],method="print")

$key
[1] 1446336000000

$doc_count
[1] 35332

$group_by_state
$group_by_state$doc_count_error_upper_bound
[1] 0

$group_by_state$sum_other_doc_count
[1] 0

$group_by_state$buckets
$group_by_state$buckets[[1]]
$group_by_state$buckets[[1]]$key
[1] "detail"

$group_by_state$buckets[[1]]$doc_count
[1] 876
```

There is a "key" value here right at the top here (1446336000000) that I am interested in (lets call it "time bucket key").

Within each day(lets take day i), "v_day[[5]]$articles_over_time$buckets[[i]]$group_by_state$buckets" has more data I am interested in. This is an aggregation over each property (property is an entity in the scheme of things here).

```
page(v_day[[5]]$articles_over_time$buckets[[i]]$group_by_state$buckets,method="print")

[[1]]
[[1]]$key
[1] "detail"

[[1]]$doc_count
[1] 876


[[2]]
[[2]]$key
[1] "ff8081814fdf2a9f014fdf80b05302e0"

[[2]]$doc_count
[1] 157


[[3]]
[[3]]$key
[1] "ff80818150a7d5930150a82abbc50477"

[[3]]$doc_count
[1] 63


[[4]]
[[4]]$key
[1] "ff8081814ff5f428014ffb5de99f1da5"

[[4]]$doc_count
[1] 57


[[5]]
[[5]]$key
[1] "ff8081815038099101503823fe5d00d9"

[[5]]$doc_count
[1] 56
```

This shows data over 5 properties in day i, each property has a "key" (lets call it "property bucket key") and a "doc_count" that I am interested in.

Eventually I want a data frame with "time bucket key", "property bucket key", "doc count".

Currently I am looping over using the below code:

```
  v <- NULL
  ndays <- length(v_day[[5]]$articles_over_time$buckets)

  for (i in 1:ndays) {
  v1 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(v_day[[5]]$articles_over_time$buckets[[i]]$group_by_state$buckets, data.frame))
  th_dt <- as.POSIXct(v_day[[5]]$articles_over_time$buckets[[i]]$key / 1000, origin="1970-01-01")
  v1$view_date <- th_dt
  v <- rbind(v, v1)
  msg <- sprintf("Read views for %s. Found %d \n", th_dt, sum(v1$doc_count))
  cat(msg)
  }
  v
```

Comment: Have you tried using bind_rows() in dplyr? Much faster to collapse the list that way and then extract and convert the fields you want.

Comment: Tried bind_rows(). It gives an error Error: object at index 1 not a data.frame. I think this is a list where embedded structure is not a df

Comment: `bind_rows()` expects each element to be a `data.frame`. you'd need to convert each to a df first. `data.table::rbindlist()`  is a fast option for binding lists together - though not sure if it will deal with nested lists easily - i could try to return df's in `elastic` pkg, but the data returned is so variable it's not worth it

Comment: Tough to get exactly right without a reproducible example. But I often end up with nested versions of bind_rows(bind_rows()) or bind_rows(list(df1,df2)), for example. But perhaps as @sckott mentioned, the data.table::rbindlist() version would be easier. I often need a few tries to get the nesting of lists/data.frames within bind_rows right.